How to get better log statements in an expo react native project?
I sometimes cannot figure out which line triggered the console.log statement and I have difficulties reading the json structure inline.
Is there a way to beautify the log statements and include the line number and file name?

I tried searching for it but could not find a solution for expo projects.
